# The grid Button command executes but does nothing in the function I want

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm making a game and two buttons should appear on the ranking grid. The options are: If you want to play a new game or end the game. I tried this way:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Ranking:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.partidas = []

def agregar_partida_terminada(self, partida):
    self.partidas.append(partida)
    self.calcular_promedio()

def calcular_promedio(self):
    for partida in self.partidas:
        for jugador in list(partida.keys()):
            lista_cantidad_de_intentos = [partida[jugador]['intentos'] for partida in self.partidas]
            partida[jugador]['promedio'] = sum(lista_cantidad_de_intentos) / len(lista_cantidad_de_intentos)

def generar_ranking(self):
    self.raiz = tk.Tk()
    self.raiz.title("Ranking")

    # self.raiz.configure(bg="#fff")

    valores_tabla = [['J', 'C', 'T', 'P']]
    ultima_partida = self.partidas[-1]
    for jugador in ultima_partida:
        valores_fila = [jugador]
        for campo in list(ultima_partida[jugador].keys()):
            valores_fila.append(ultima_partida[jugador][campo])
        valores_tabla.append(valores_fila)

    for indexFila in range(len(valores_tabla)):
        fila = valores_tabla[indexFila]
        for indexCol in range(len(fila)):
            Label(self.raiz, text=fila[indexCol]).grid(row=indexFila, column=indexCol, sticky=NSEW)
    Ranking.end_game(self)
    Ranking.new_game(self)

    self.raiz.mainloop()

def close_ranking(self):
    self.raiz.destroy()

def end_game(self):
    End_Game = tkinter.Button(self.raiz, text="Terminar partida",
                              command=lambda: [True, self.close_ranking()])
    End_Game.grid(row=4, column=0)

def new_game(self):
    New_Game = tkinter.Button(self.raiz, text="Jugar nueva partida",
                              command=lambda: [True, self.close_ranking()])
    New_Game.grid(row=4, column=3)
```

And the execution of the button must be moved here and then close the grid:

```
...

from ranking import Ranking

    if ranking.end_game() is True:

        finalizar_juego = True

    elif ranking.new_game() is True:

        finalizar_partida = False
...
```

But when i press any button the grid close and show me this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

Answer (score 0):

Both end_game and new_game buttons have the same command, self.close_ranking, which destroys the tk application in this code snippet. Any reference to these buttons after these functions are called - as in your if statement - will get the tk error.